# Invoking subshells from script does not work if run in background

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script running in background, like:

```
su - insite1 -c "invokeTest.sh" &
```

Now this script, invokeTest.sh has contents:

```
while [ 1 ]
do
  echo "Hello World from invokeTest" >> /tmp/invokeTest
  ( exec "/tmp/test.sh" )
done
```

Although it prints, "Hello World from invokeTest" it does not call test.sh.

My question:
Is there any way to call test.sh in infinite while loop directly from `su - insite1 -c" "`so that we can totally skip `invokeTest.sh` itself (but test.sh needs to run in background"?

If no, how to make sure test.sh is called from `invokeTest.sh`?

Comment: How do you know that `test.sh` isn't invoked? Would you be able to differentiate between it failing and not being invoked at all?

Comment: There's no difference between `( exec command )` and just `command`.

Comment: @thatotherguy Because it prints an echo output to log as well, and i don't see the logs created. Yes, i didn't see the exit status, but it is nothing but just as simple as "echo Hello" so less chances of failing

Comment: If you put another `echo` after `( exec "/tmp/test.sh" )`, do you see that?

Comment: @Barmar I know, but i had no other choice as nothing was working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question about running the command without a script, you can put any shell commands into the `-c` argument, including a `while` loop. So you can write:

```
su - insite1 -c 'while :; do echo "Hello World" >> /tmp/invokeTest; /tmp/test.sh; done' &
```

Comment: Thanks, this is cool, but any clue why the subshell invocation in background in invokeTest.sh did not work?

Comment: no idea at all. Does it only happen when you use `su`? What if you run `su` but don't run it in the background?

Comment: Does `test.sh` try to read from the terminal? That would cause it to stop if it's in the background.

Comment: No, test.sh is `echo "Hello World" >> a.txt`

Comment: Okay, seems like it works. I was missing something earlier. Thanks.